# Unable to create custom php app in shopify

Tags: php, shopify, artisan-migrate

I am trying to create a PHP app in Shopify. But when I try to create the app it is showing as error mentioned below

```
Application key set successfully.
┃ 
┃    Illuminate\Database\QueryException 
┃ 
┃   could not find driver (SQL: PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;)
┃ 
┃   at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:712
┃     708▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
┃     709▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
┃     710▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
┃     711▕         catch (Exception $e) {
┃   ➜ 712▕             throw new QueryException(
┃     713▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
┃     714▕             );
┃     715▕         }
┃     716▕     }
┃ 
┃       +38 vendor frames 
┃   39  artisan:37
┃       Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
┗━━ Failed to set up the app ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ (0.18s) ━━
┏━━ Error ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
┃ ✗ System call failed: PHP artisan migrate
```

Does anyone have a solution for this? I have enabled all the extensions.

Comment: Have you enabled pdo_sqlite on php extensions?

Comment: I have enabled all the extensions that needs to be.